# SQLite data lost after rebooting Raspberry pi

Tags: python, database, sqlite, raspberry-pi

I have a python program running on Raspberry pi which collects the data from machine and sends it to Server via MQTT. The Raspberry pi also have Buffer database based on SQLite. Raspberry pi saves data into this Buffer database in case there is no Connection to MQTT.

The data is successfully stored into Buffer database but data gets lost after rebooting Raspberry pi.

```
connection = sqlite3.connect("BufferDB.db")
cursor=connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("CREATE table IF NOT EXISTS BufferTable1 (MQTTWert TEXT)")
connection.commit()
connection.close()
```

Comment: What exactly is "lost". Is the file gone?

Comment: File stays but no data inside

Comment: There is no insert statement in the code you have posted, so nothing will be added to the table

Comment: I added INSERT Statement. I can see that it adds to the SQLite database but once I reboot Raspberry, the data gets lost